# phone number attaches to the existing contact when inserting new contact into android contacts

Tags: android, insert, contactscontract

I am developing a `sync adapter` to `sync contacts` in the phone with an `ERP system`.
Everything works fine on the emulator, but on the phone I get new phone numbers attached to already existing contacts which were created "by hand".

```
int rawContactInsertIndex =0;
    // Add new items http://techblogon.com/insert-new-contact-in-android-code-example/
    for (RestAPIContactParser.Entry e : entryMap.values()) {
                    rawContactInsertIndex = batch.size();
...
 batch.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.SOURCE_ID, e.code)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, ACCOUNT_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_NAME) 
                     rawContactInsertIndex)
                    .build());
... batch.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, e.phone)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                                                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                        .build());
```

when I delete my account contacts, phone numbers which were inserted also gets deleted from the existing contacts.
I even created a new contact on the emulator then tried to sync and everything was fine, new phone numbers weren't attached to the old contacts.
Any ideas?
edited: Its is not clear what is the database structure of the RawContacts table. Shall do something like

```
 rawContactInsertIndex =max(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID)+1
```

and then increment rawContactInsertIndex instead of rawContactInsertIndex = batch.size()?

Comment: I have deleted all the contacts from phone manually, then imported .vcf from the backup, then installed my sync adapter and the problem has gone. As far as I understand I had some orphans in the contacts.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior in Android, whenever a new `RawContact` is inserted, the system will try check if that new `RawContact` is a duplicate of an existing `Contact`, and try to join that new `RawContact` into that existing `Contact` using the [`AggregationExceptions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.html) table.
It uses names, phones and emails to seek our potential existing contacts for merge.

If you don't want your new RawContact to me merged into an existing contacts (though, you should reconsider this is you don't want your users to complain about duplicate contacts), you can add a `TYPE_KEEP_SEPARATE` rule to `AggregationExceptions`, specifying your `RawContact` should not be joined:

```
ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(AggregationExceptions.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValue(AggregationExceptions.TYPE, AggregationExceptions.TYPE_KEEP_SEPARATE)
    .withValue(AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID1, yourNewRawContact)
    .withValue(AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID2, anExistingRawContact)
    .build();
```

> when I delete my account contacts...

Never delete `Contacts` that were created as part of your account, as it may delete `RawContacts` that are not related to your account. Only delete your **RawContacts**  and the related Contacts would be auto-deleted if needed.

> Shall do something like
>
> rawContactInsertIndex =max(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID)+1

No! The `RawContact` ID is auto-assigned, don't set it yourself.
You should do:

```
.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
```

And make sure you `applyBatch` all related operations together in the same batch.

Comment: Thanks about explaining AggregationExceptions. I deleted my  account rawcontacts many times, with no side effects, I always specify my account name and type as query parameters when I delete rawcontacts.

Comment: yes, that's good, just be careful to delete only `RawContacts` never delete `Contacts`, as you might be deleting other accounts' data.